# Pi3 + OpenVpn + Router

Tags: networking, router, vpn, raspberry-pi

Sorry if some of this will not make sense, as I am quite a noob when it comes to network engineering. I would like somw guidance on an OpenVpn setup using Raspberry Pi3 B.

Basically, I have one of the popular commercial VPN subscriptions (which uses OpenVpn) and would like to set up my Raspberry Pi3 B in the following way: 1. Connect Pi to my main router (one of the mainstream Huawei models) 2. Set up an OpenVPN client on Pi and connect to my VPN subscription. 3. Connect a separate router (Bufallo N300 v1, ddwrt version doesn't properly support it) through usb->ethernet. 4. Set up a wifi on that router which will connect to the internet through Pi via the VPN connection.

tl;dr; - I want a 'secure' wifi which would connect through VPN.

Thank you.

Comment: IMHO, that makes more sense the other way around: Connect the Pi 3 to your real router using Ethernet and then host the VPN Wi-Fi on the Pi’s own Wi-Fi interface. // That being said, I feel your question is too broad. You need to ask for something more concrete than “some guidance”.

Comment: DD-wrt definitely supports OpenVPN... Did you mean you don't know how to connect it to the paid service? It would make more sense to do it as @Daniel b stated, or use the dd-wrt router as the VPN server or client directly. What exactly are you trying to achieve? This question is very broad.

Comment: I want a dedicated router which would be connected to internet using openvpn client. That Buffalo router is 8 years old, it supports quite an old version of ddwrt and I couldn't find a way to configure it to work with my vpn subscription.